# Workaround SpamAssassin Y2K10 Bug (Mac OS X Server)

Tags: spam, mac-osx-server, osx-snow-leopard, spamassassin

Bug Report: https://issues.apache.org/SpamAssassin/show_bug.cgi?id=6269

It turns out that SpamAssassin is adding a score of 3.2 (FH_DATE_PAST_20XX) to all email going through my mail server (Mac OS X 10.6 Server) because of the above bug.

See log:

```
Jan  1 09:46:36 mail.example.com /usr/bin/amavisd[25021]: (25021-16) SPAM, <opadyoceb8552@superonline.com> -> <scrubbed@joemedia.tv>, Yes, score=11.101 tag=2 tag2=6 kill=6 tests=[BAYES_99=3.5, FH_DATE_PAST_20XX=3.188, HTML_IMAGE_ONLY_32=1.778, HTML_IMAGE_RATIO_02=0.383, HTML_MESSAGE=0.001, MIME_HTML_ONLY=1.457, RDNS_NONE=0.1, SPF_FAIL=0.693, SPF_HELO_FAIL=0.001], autolearn=no, quarantine fydtn7Bx7ffD (junk@example.com)
```

In the bug the rule is defined in `/rulesrc/sandbox/emailed/00_FVGT_File001.cf` however this does not exist on Mac OS X - does any know where this rule is defined on Mac OS X Server? There are no files prepended with 00_ in `/usr/share/spamassassin/` which is where I assumed it would be.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well a little patience and it showed up on one of my mailing lists (and now on Apple's KBase: [TS3187](http://support.apple.com/kb/TS3187)):

Either:

1) Add to `/etc/mail/spamassassin.conf`

```
 score FH_DATE_PAST_20XX 0.0
```

or

2) Fix the rule in `/usr/share/spamassassin/72_active.cf` by replacing the `FH_DATE_PAST_20XX` line with:

```
header   FH_DATE_PAST_20XX    Date =~ /20[2-9][0-9]/ [if-unset: 2006]
```

or

3) Run `sa-update` and that will fix it as well. (Thanks to [Matthew Bryant](http://discussions.apple.com/thread.jspa?threadID=2284982&tstart=0))

```
sudo sa-update --nogpg --updatedir /etc/mail/spamassassin --debug
```

Comment: Doesn't this fix merely defer the pain for another 10 years - when it strikes again?

Comment: Answer (to my comment/question): yes - that's correct.  The SpamAssassin team is aware of it and will fix the problem properly in due course -- see the bug report link in the question.

Answer (score 0):

I had to modify /private/etc/mail/spamassassin/00_FVGT_File001.cf and then restart the mail service instead.

Updating /usr/share/spamassassin/72_active.cf did nothing for me.

(Mac OS X Server 10.6.2, pretty much a vanilla install)

Comment: @James: Odd. My 10.6.2 install only had the local.cf in `/private/etc/mail/spamassassin` and it's a pretty vanilla install.