# Any Y2K10 bugs?

Tags: untagged

There seem to have been few year 2010 bugs cropping up in real life (EFTPOS machines belonging to BoQ in Australia thought it was [2016](http://www.smh.com.au/technology/technology-news/nye-a-fizzer-as-eftpos-terminals-party-like-its-2016-20100104-loo8.html)) as well as the SpamAssassin [hiccup](https://serverfault.com/questions/98723/workaround-spamassassin-y2k10-bug-mac-os-x-server) - have there been any other serverfault-like issues occurring as a result ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For those of us in Academia there's [Endnote](http://www.endnote.com/support/Faqs/Import/faq20.asp)...

Even better, thankfully somebody has [patched the Newton](http://arstechnica.com/apple/news/2009/06/impending-newton-y2k10-apocalypse-narrowly-averted.ars) so it can handle post Y2K10 dates - Phew.   What a hero!

Answer (score 2):

http://www.avg.com/gb-en/download-update

I'm not sure how long they'll stay broken, but the latest database updates are dated `January 1 2000` and `January 3 2000`!!

You would have thought people would have learned lessons after the Y2K fiasco, but obviously not!

Comment: Perhaps people have become complacent since Y2K was such a non-event?

Comment: @petertonoli: People have become far too complacent about it, going back to the bad old days of only allowing 2-digit years in dates on forms etc.  Yes, they have forgotten already.  It is frustrating.  The only good news is that I'm unlikely to be around to help fix the mess come Y2.1K!

Answer (score 1):

http://www.guardian.co.uk/world/2010/jan/06/2010-bug-millions-germans

> A 2010 software bug has left millions of German debit and credit card holders unable to withdraw money or make payments in shops, and thousands stranded on holiday with no access to cash.

That's ironically much worse than Y2K ever was.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that Windows Mobile 6.1 and 6.5 are [affected](http://www.wmexperts.com/y2016-sms-bug); dating received SMS from 2010 as 2016!

Answer (score 0):

Our crappy in house service ticket system uses a drop down menu for years, and stopped in 2009. It turned out to be a bit more work than anticipated to fix for mundane boring reasons, but the end result is that we're good until Y2K11.

Answer (score 0):

Unix date rollover in 2038, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_2038_problem .

It's interesting to note, that history repeats itself again again, programmers still
have problems calculating a leap year.

http://www.bbc.co.uk/blogs/thereporters/rorycellanjones/2010/03/sonys_millennium_bug.html

;-)

Answer (score 0):

For several years SpamAssassin has included a rule that [e-mails from 2010 or later](http://issues.apache.org/SpamAssassin/show_bug.cgi?id=6269) get 3.2 added to their score. Apparently someone forgot to update the rule, and it took almost a month for it to be fixed. Many people are still having the problem as they haven't updated their rulesets in a long time.

I hope someone has it on their calendar to fix again before 2020 (the new date in the rule).